# A[B[C]] types in Scala i.e. nested type constructors

Tags: scala, generics, haskell

The code below compiles

```
case class A(s:Int)
case class B(s:Int)
case class Box[T](t:T)

object DoublyNestedTypes extends App {
  println("hello")
  val l=List(Box(A(1)))
  val l2=Box(A(2))::l
  println(l2)
  val l3=Box(B(1))::l2
  println(l3)    
}
```

and produces:

```
hello
List(Box(A(2)), Box(A(1)))
List(Box(B(1)), Box(A(2)), Box(A(1)))
```

Can someone explain what is going on here ? 
Why does the compilation not fail ? Or the execution at runtime?

I was expecting this to fail since the type of `l` is `List[Box[A]]` while
the type of `Box(B(1))` is `Box[B]`, so how can I prepend `Box[B]` to `List[Box[A]]` ?

What is the type of `l3` now ?

Does this have to do something with type erasure?

Would the equivalent code fail at compile time in Haskell ? (My feeling is that it would.)

Comment: This is based on subtyping.. The comparable Haskell code would be something evilish involving existentials or a `data Super = SupA A | SupB B` type construction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When having a value `a` of type `A` and a list `l` of elements of type `B`, `a :: l` will not fail but produce a list of type `List[C]` where `C` is the *least upper bound* of types `A` and `B` - that is, their most specific common supertype. And if types `A` and `B` are completely unrelated, you'll just get a `List[Any]`. This is reflected by the signature of `::` operator (`a :: l` is equivalent to `l.::(a)`):

```
sealed abstract class List[+A] {
  def ::[B >: A] (x: B): List[B] = ...
}
```

You are right that something like this would not compile in Haskell and that is simply because there is no such thing as subtyping in Haskell, so the notion of *least upper bound* doesn't make any sense.

Whether it is good or bad that Scala does it like this is a very controversial issue.